# Where do onclick() tags look for functions in order?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, onclick

JS is loaded from seperate file which is working. It is also guaranteed that the element with onclick() is loading after the script as it is created by it. **Im not sure where html onclick() looks for script functions so I wanted to ask to clear up why this isnt working.**

Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: remove is not defined
at HTMLElement.onclick ((index):1:1)

grey (index) is my html page. I dont really know whats going on with the generated orange (index)

[image]

html:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'index' %}" class="form-div" onsubmit="return false;">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="title">
                <i class='bx bx-palette' ></i>
              <h2>Interests</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <p>Please enter your interests for improved suggestions</p>
              <ul><input id="input" class="input" type="text" spellcheck="false"></ul>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <p><span>10</span> tags are remaining</p>
              <button>Remove All</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        <button id="regbtn" type="submit" class="form-group btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
```

js:

```
    function createTag() {
        ul.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => li.remove());
        tags.slice().reverse().forEach(tag =>{
            let liTag = `<li>${tag} <i class="uit uit-multiply" onclick="remove(this, '${tag}')"></i></li>`;
            ul.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", liTag);
        });
        countTags();
    }

    function remove(element, tag) {
        let index  = tags.indexOf(tag);
        tags = [...tags.slice(0, index), ...tags.slice(index + 1)];
        element.parentElement.remove();
        countTags();
    }
```

Comment: the function should be present on the global object (`window` or `globalThis`)- have you considered `addEventListener` instead

Comment: @JaromandaX you're correct its inside a function in the js file. Thanks.

Comment: An `<input>` tag directly inside a `<ul>` is not valid HTML.

Comment: It all depends on exactly how those functions are defined. The way you posted them, if they're in a JS file at the outer level, they should work. If they're imported as part of a module, they won't. You haven't posted enough context to make it clear.

Comment: @Pointy This code is from someone else but that part of the html seems to work for me.

Comment: Well browsers compensate for bad HTML, but they do it according to their own rules and you can't control it. It's much *much* better to have valid markup.